# parent process fails to read() from STDIN after fork()

Tags: c, parallel-processing, io, signals

I want to test a signal-program from *CSAPP*(*Computer System A Programmer's Perspective*) on my Ubuntu 16.04 server. it goes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int MAXBUF = 50 ;

ssize_t Sio_puts(char s[]) {
    return write(STDOUT_FILENO, s, strlen(s)) ;
}

void sio_error(char s[]) {
    Sio_puts(s) ;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE) ;

    return ;
}

void unix_error(const char* msg) {
    int errnum = errno ;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s (%d: %s)\n", msg, errnum, strerror(errnum)) ;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE) ;
}

pid_t Fork(void) {
    pid_t pid ;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        unix_error("fork error") ;
    }

    return pid ;
}

void handler1(int sig) {
    int olderrno = errno ;
    if ((waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)) < 0) {
        sio_error("waitpid error") ;
    }
    Sio_puts("Handler reaped child\n");
    sleep(1000) ;
    errno = olderrno ;
}

void handler2(int sig) {
    int olderrno = errno ;
    while ((waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)) > 0) {
        Sio_puts("Handler reaped child\n");
    }
    if (errno != ECHILD) {
        sio_error("waitpid error") ;
    }
    sleep(1000) ;
    errno = olderrno ;
}

int main() {
    int i, n ;
    char buf[MAXBUF] ;
    if (signal(SIGCHLD, handler2) == SIG_ERR) {
        unix_error("signal error") ;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++ i) {
        if (Fork() == 0) {
            printf("Hello from child %d\n", (int)getpid()) ;
            exit(0) ;
        }
    }

    printf("read line:\n") ;
    if ( (n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf))) < 0 ) {
        unix_error("read") ;
    }
    //scanf("%s\n", buf) ;

    printf("Parent processing input\n") ;
    while (1) ;

    exit(0) ;
}
```

But I fail to read anything from stdin after the fork() loop.

```
read line:
Hello from child 21596
Hello from child 21597
Handler reaped child
Handler reaped child
Hello from child 21598
Handler reaped child
sdasd
sadas
^C
```

'Parent processing input' statement never gets printed, so I think the programmer is blocked by read().

Comment: [read manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html): "*On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file)*". That is, you need to check for a 0 `read` return value and enter EOF to terminate the loop. How to input EOF depends on the terminal - for Linux it is ctrl-D. Don't enter ctrl-C as that will just terminate the program.

Answer (score 2):

Running your program under `strace` shows that it `sleep`s for 1000s.

```
wait4(-1, NULL, 0, NULL)                = 696580
write(1, "Handler reaped child\n", 21Handler reaped child
)  = 21
wait4(-1, NULL, 0, NULL)                = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=1000, tv_nsec=0}, ^Cstrace: Process 696577 detached
 <detached ...>
```

You should delete the `sleep(1000)` calls, unless you are willing to wait for 17 minutes before expecting a response from your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The unit of sleep() is s instead of ms.